# CSS Property Border-Color Not Working

Tags: css, border

I have issue with border-color. It didn't work. I'm new to css here is the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/zeburrehman/aFzKy/151/

```
<div id="box">
Hello! The color of box border should be red!!
</div>​

#box {
border-color: red;
}​
```

Comment: You need to add the `width` and `style` of the border.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

By default the `border-width` is `0` and `border-style` is `none`

So you need to set them to `border-width:1px` and `border-style:solid`. You can combine all the border properties into one as below:

```
#box {
    border:1px solid red
}
```

Comment: Please check it.... Here is updated fiddle. i set separately
style and size but it give me black color where as i want red color.
http://jsfiddle.net/zeburrehman/aFzKy/152/

Comment: remove `border:1px` from your fiddle. Updated here - http://jsfiddle.net/aFzKy/153/

Comment: The reason border:1px was causing problems is because CSS is parsed from top to bottom. And styles are overridden in this order. When you specify `border:1px`, default values are assigned to border-style and border-color

Answer (score 6):

I had an issue where it seemed that `border-color` was not being respected, confusingly it even showed having the right color in the style inspector in Chrome (possibly a Chrome bug).  The key thing for me was that if the shorthand border style is specified, it sets all three aspects of the border style, regardless of if they are included or not so:

```
border-left: 1px;
```

Actually overwrites both the `border-left-style` and `border-left-color` properties even though they weren't included.  This can for example cause an inherited style to be overridden and appear not to work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the border style:

```
#box {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#box{
    border:3px solid #aacfac;
    }
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use hex color code for red as well, which is `#ff0000` (RGB). 100% Red, 0% Green and 0% Blue if you want pure red color.

```
#box {
   border: 2px solid #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :
border: 5px solid red;

Comment: Please check this link. I want to use only border-color.. http://jsfiddle.net/zeburrehman/aFzKy/152/

Comment: A very old question but might help if someone are facing this problem. The solution is: move the boder-color property to the end. https://jsfiddle.net/zeburrehman/aFzKy/152/