# how to make a div show

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a foot print for a cool look, but it won't show

here's my code:

```css
.footprint {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border-color: gray;
  border: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footprint"></div>
```

Comment: see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Answer (score -1):

welcome to SO!

Somebody already found a solution to your problem here:
[CSS Property Border-Color Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156674/css-property-border-color-not-working)

A div by default has no border-style and no border-width, therefore the border will not be shown.